# Unity: неправильное расположение Text Mesh

Tags: unity3d, текст

В чем заключается моя проблема.
Есть сцена Intro, в ней текст и анимация поочерёдно появляются и затухают, компонент для текста используется Text Mesh. В Unity текст ведёт себя как надо(см. скрин 1), но после компиляции и установки на телефон (это Xiaomi Redmi Note 4) положение, масштаб и угол поворота изменяются (см. скрин 2).
Гугл не дал ничего дельного да и я сам впервые с таким встречаюсь.

При проверке на тестовой сборке таких проблем не обнаружено, устанавливал все в точности с оригиналом.

При многократной проверке было замечено следующее: Начальная точка (Anchor) устанавливается в начало координат, например: если изменить Anchor на Middle Center, то будет видно центральную часть текста (как на скрине). А если Anchor установить на Top Left, то соответственно будет видно верхнюю левую часть текста.

В Player Settings установлена портретная ориентация.

cкрин 1.
[image: Как выглядит в Unity]
скрин 2.
[image: Как выглядит в телефоне]

Comment: а это случайно не с ориентацией связано? пробовали landscape режим отключать?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ если вы имеете ввиду Player Settings, то там Default Orientation стоит на Portrait, если бы было так просто я бы не обращался за помощью сюда

Answer (score 0):

Все UI-элементы должны быть потомками игровых объектов, к которым присоединен Canvas.